# Why the $O(t^2)$ part in $L(t)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $f$ the isoperipetric quotient and $P$ an equilateral $n$-gon. (See [Sound of Symmetry](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rowlett/monthly.pdf) for more detail)

Since $f$ is scale invariant, then we shall assume that the sides of $P$ all have length equal to one. Consider the edge between two vertices $\nu_i$ and $\nu_{i+1}$, where the vertices are considered modulo $n$. Denote by $\{\gamma_i\}_{i=1}^n$ the set of interior angles of $P$, and the exterior angles $\alpha_i := \pi - \gamma_i$. Consider moving the edge between $\nu_i$ and $\nu_{i+1}$ in the direction of the outward normal to this edge. Let $t$ denote the distance the edge is translated. Then the perimeter $$L(t) = L + t(\csc \alpha_i - \cot \alpha_i) + t(\csc \alpha_{i+1} - \cot \alpha_{i+1})\color{red}{+ O(t^2)},$$ where $L$ is the perimeter of $P$ at $t=0$.

[image]

I thought that $$L(t) = L(0) + t((\csc \alpha_i - \cot \alpha_i) + (\csc \alpha_{i+1} - \cot \alpha_{i+1})) , $$ but I have difficulty seeing why they added $O(t^2).$

**Question :** Why do we have to add the part $O(t^2)$ at the equation of perimeter?

**P.S.** I know that there exists a similar question, but knowing that it is not the same : [Why the $O(t^2)$ part in $L(t) = L + t(\csc \alpha_i - \cot \alpha_i +\csc \alpha_{i+1} - \cot \alpha_{i+1}) + O(t^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880116/why-the-ot2-part-in-lt-l-t-csc-alpha-i-cot-alpha-i-csc-alph).

Comment: It looks like the difference between this question and the previous one is that, in the previous question, you accepted an answer that dealt just with area rather than perimeter.

Comment: @Semiclassical It's because initially, I asked just for the area, and I think I had edited the question a few days later to add the perimeter. However, the question hasn't been answered thereafter.

Comment: @Semiclassical You could always answer on the initial page. I wanted to write another question just for the perimeter instead of mixing up the perimeter and the area on the same page. If It was the case, then I could delete that question.